# Map an AnyPublisher to another AnyPublisher

Tags: swift, combine

I have this code:

```
class ViewModel {

    let email = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("")

    private var isEmailValid: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>?

    var emailColor: AnyPublisher<UIColor, Never>?


    private func validateEmail(email: String) -> Bool { return email == "1234@gmail.com" }
    private func emailColor(isValid: Bool) -> UIColor { return isValid ? UIColor.black : 
UIColor.red }

    public func setupPublishers() {
        isEmailValid = email
        .map { self.validateEmail(email: $0) }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        emailColor = email
        .map { self.emailColor(isValid: self.validateEmail(email: $0)) }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

In the function setupPublishers, I create isEmailValid as a map from the CurrentValueSubject 'email'.
I wish to map it directly from 'isEmailValid', but if I do this:

```
        emailColor = isEmailValid
        .map { self.emailColor(isValid: $0) }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>' to expected argument type 'Bool'
Value of type 'UIColor?' has no member 'eraseToAnyPublisher'
```

Which obviously indicates that mapping from the publisher gives me the actual value instead of another publisher.
So how could I achieve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message doesn't make any sense, the real error was that `isEmailValid` is `Optional`, so you need to use optional chaining on it to be able to call `map`.

```
emailColor = isEmailValid?
        .map { self.emailColor(isValid: $0) }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: thanks, interestingly, the compiler did not make me notice that. This turned out to be a very basic mistake :)